# How can I copy paste files on BlueStacks?

Tags: bluestacks

I have to copy-paste files between different folders of the BlueStacks itself. When I try to select a file in ES Explorer, it opens automatically.

While there are tons of articles on how to copy-paste files between computer and emulator, I haven't yet found anything dealing with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is:

1. Winrar the files/folders you need to cut or move.
2. Extract the files/folders into the target destination (the Winrar in bluestack has this feature to prompt destination for the intended files/folder to be extracted).

You can download Winrar from Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

you go to setting , then storage ,then explore  and find the file you want to move/copy